# Count a NVARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to "count" how often a certain ID is listed in a Table 1 and group it by ConsumerID and the frequency in table 2:

**Table 1**:

```
ConsumerID
----------
1A
1A
1B
1C
1C
```

This is the expected behaviour:

**Table 2**:

```
Consumer ID | Frequency
------------+----------
   1A       |    2
   1B       |    1
   1C       |    2
```

The column `ConsumerID` is of type `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: have you tried this at all? you want a simple count with a group by

Comment: `select consumerID, count(*) from your_table group by consumerID`

Comment: thanks, that works. I tried but was working with sum and that was the wrong approach

Comment: This is literally an example case of when to use count. o_o